# Showing that $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $\sin 2x=x$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

This is an A level question. For better understanding, I will attach a screenshot of the question and the mark scheme.

Question:

[image]

Here's what I have done:

$$A(OBA) = \frac 12r^2α$$ [basic formula for area of sector]

$$A(ONB) = \frac 12r \sin(\frac {BN}{r})$$ [basic formula for area of triangle]

$$2\frac 12r \sin(\frac {BN}{r}) = \frac 12r^2α$$ [because A(ONB) is half A(OBA)]

$$2 \sin(\frac {BN}{r}) = rα$$
[simplifying the equation]

And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed answer is absolutely correct. 
I don't know how the area of triangle happens to be $1\over 2$rsin($BN\over r$) 
but the area of triangle is $1\over 2$bh  (base x height) 
base = $r\sin(\alpha)$ ;
height = $r\cos(\alpha)$

Comment: In fact $\sin(\alpha) =$ $BN\over r$

Comment: Aha. I understood my mistake. Even after that, I'm getting $4α = sin2α$ and not $α = sin2α$.

Comment: Try solving again.     $1\over 2$$r^2$$\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$  is the area of the triangle.  =>  $1\over 4$$r^2$$\sin(2\alpha)$    = half( $1\over 2$$r^2$$\alpha$)